# How to add/remove attributes in a document before returning it in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am trying to query a document. Before I return the document, I need to delete some attributes like `_id`, `_rev` and add a few other calculated attributes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove some attributes you can use the `UNSET`  functions:

```
FOR item in collection
    RETURN UNSET(item, "_id", "_key", "_rev")
```

Regarding calculating new attributes it mostly depends on what you want to achieve but there are a lot of available functions in AQL.
If you give us a bit more details we could find what works for you!

Sources:

- UNSET function https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#unset
- Documentation about AQL functions: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions.html